# Python - Create list out of all variables in same .py file

Tags: python

So I have this code below of categories and I will sometimes update it by adding a new category, then I have to manually add that category to the list at the bottom `INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES` it'd be much easier if this list was automatically updated whenever I create a new `dict` variable. Is there a way to do this? I export the `INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES` variable and use it elsewhere so if I can set that variable name to a list of all other variables that'd be great. This file will only contain dicts of categories and the list of all of them at the bottom.

`categories.py`

```
# Categories
ART = dict(name='Art', emoji='')
CULINARY = dict(name='Culinary', emoji='')
DIET = dict(name='Diet', emoji='')
DIY = dict(name='DIY', emoji='')
FINANCE = dict(name='Finance', emoji='')
FITNESS = dict(name='Fitness', emoji='')
GAMING = dict(name='Gaming', emoji='️')
MARTIAL_ARTS = dict(name='Martial Arts', emoji='')
MUSIC = dict(name='Music', emoji='')
RELATIONSHIP = dict(name='Relationship', emoji='')
SELF_CARE = dict(name='Self-Care', emoji='')
SELF_IMPROVEMENT = dict(name='Self-Improvement', emoji='✨')
STREAMING = dict(name='Streaming', emoji='⏺️')
TRAVEL = dict(name='Travel', emoji='✈️')
WEIGHT_TRAINING = dict(name='Weight Training', emoji='️')

INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES = [ART, CULINARY, DIET, DIY, FITNESS, GAMING, MARTIAL_ARTS, MUSIC,
                           RELATIONSHIP, SELF_IMPROVEMENT, SELF_CARE, STREAMING, TRAVEL,
                           WEIGHT_TRAINING]
```

Comment: Don't use all these unrelated variables, use a dict.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you mean a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: That's what it will be, yes.

Comment: what's the rational behind that?

Comment: why can't you make just one dictionary out of this?

Comment: Having a dictionary holding these will be easier to manage, keys with the variable names that you have created and values as the dict() call. That way you can have a list comprehension to get the variable names into a list easily, without worrying about updating names at multiple places.

Comment: @SiddharthaPramanik that's fair. I don't currently use that variable beyond iterating through it to generate each dict in the list in a DB, but if my needs expand beyond that your suggestion isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a list that update itself when you add this kind of global values, here what you need:

```py
# Categories
ART = dict(name='Art', emoji='')
CULINARY = dict(name='Culinary', emoji='')
DIET = dict(name='Diet', emoji='')
DIY = dict(name='DIY', emoji='')
FINANCE = dict(name='Finance', emoji='')
FITNESS = dict(name='Fitness', emoji='')
GAMING = dict(name='Gaming', emoji='️')
MARTIAL_ARTS = dict(name='Martial Arts', emoji='')
MUSIC = dict(name='Music', emoji='')
RELATIONSHIP = dict(name='Relationship', emoji='')
SELF_CARE = dict(name='Self-Care', emoji='')
SELF_IMPROVEMENT = dict(name='Self-Improvement', emoji='✨')
STREAMING = dict(name='Streaming', emoji='⏺️')
TRAVEL = dict(name='Travel', emoji='✈️')
WEIGHT_TRAINING = dict(name='Weight Training', emoji='️')

INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES = [value for name, value in globals().items() if
                           name.isupper()]
```

This go through all values in [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and
check if the name of the value is upper case. If it met the criteria, it is a category and we add it to the categories list.

But as said in comments: a dictionary is better:

```py
# Categories
INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES = {
    'Art': {'emoji': ''},
    'Culinary': {'emoji': ''},
    'Diet': {'emoji': ''},
    'DIY': {'emoji': ''},
    'Finance': {'emoji': ''},
    'Fitness': {'emoji': ''},
    'Gaming': {'emoji': '️'},
    'Martial Arts': {'emoji': ''},
    'Music': {'emoji': ''},
    'Relationship': {'emoji': ''},
    'Self-Care': {'emoji': ''},
    'Self-Improvement': {'emoji': '✨'},
    'Streaming': {'emoji': '⏺️'},
    'Travel': {'emoji': '✈️'},
    'Weight Training': {'emoji': '️'},
}
```

Comment: The dict is the only sane way to go...

Comment: With some legacy code, you must stick to bad practices if you can't change everything :) But yes, I agree, that's why I added the part about the dict.

Comment: I hope you never get coerced to do such things! ;)

Comment: Unfortunatly yes... So much pain... *vietnam flashes*

Comment: If the asker didn't know about this, probably it's good to mention that everything in globals that meets the criteria will be added to the list

Comment: You're right, I edit the answer

Comment: This solution works but it has some cons. One con is enforcing the declaration of variables in only one .py file [as of the use of `globals()`].  Second con is that it enforces the naming convention of UPPER-CASE which requires no other variables to be written and that new variables would follow the same convention. The developer has to remember to write the variables above the `INITIAL_GOAL_CATEGORIES` or they just wont appear. There is a different approach without having all these constraints.